# Pythonic way to join proximal segments in a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a 2D `numpy` array that represents fragmented time segments as begin/end times. I've devised a way to join the segments when they are proximal (less than some minimum gap length):

```
def join_proximal_segments(original_segments, min_gap):

  begins = np.array([original_segments.T[0, 0]])
  ends = np.array([])

  for i in np.arange(len(original_segments)-1):

    if((original_segments.T[0, i+1] - original_segments.T[1, i]) > min_gap):

      begins = np.append(begins, original_segments.T[1, i])
      ends = np.append(ends, original_segments.T[0, i+1])

  ends = np.append(ends, original_segments.T[1, -1])

  joined_segments = np.array([begins, ends]).T

  return joined_segments
```

It seems quite inelegant. Is there a more direct way to approach this problem using `numpy`?

Edit: an example array

```
detections = np.array([[2, 60],[62, 78],[97, 105],[255, 340],[343, 347]])
```

Comment: some example data would be helpful

Comment: @scleronomic please see edit with an example input array

Comment: And what is `min_gap` and what array do you expect as output?

Comment: `min_gap` is a scalar (in this case, in seconds), and i was hoping for an output similar to `detections` but with shape (m, 2), where in this case m ≤ 5.

Comment: I updated my answer, does this provide the wanted result?
But nevertheless it is always useful to by explicit about what you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your problem fully but I hope this example helps you enough to figure out the vectorisation of your problem:

```py
import numpy as np

min_gap = 10
original_segments = np.array([[  2,  60],
                              [ 62,  78],
                              [ 97, 105],
                              [255, 340],
                              [343, 347]])


def join_proximal_segments(original_segments, min_gap):
    diff = original_segments[1:, 0] - original_segments[:-1, 1]
    diff_bool = diff > min_gap

    joined_segments = np.empty((sum(diff_bool)+1, 2),
                                 dtype=original_segments.dtype)
    # beginnings
    joined_segments[0, 0] = original_segments[0, 0]
    joined_segments[1:, 0] = original_segments[:-1, 1][diff_bool]
    # ends
    joined_segments[:-1, 1] = original_segments[1:, 0][diff_bool]
    joined_segments[-1, 1] = original_segments[-1, 1]

    return joined_segments


print(join_proximal_segments(original_segments, min_gap))
# [[  2  97]
#  [ 78 255]
#  [105 347]]
```